# dired - view file in other window?

Tags: dired

Is there some way to have two windows open with a dired buffer in one and a file view of current file in the other?

**v** loads the file into the dired buffer.

**o** loads the file into the other window but changes focus.

I would like the ability to browse the contents of a directory using two windows, but can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default keybinding `C-o` bound to the command `dired-display-file`, which displays the file in another window *without* changing focus.

[The list of all the major-mode keybindings is displayed on hitting `C-h m` or calling the command `M-x describe-keymap` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<dired-mode-map>`.]

Comment: Many thanks. I had overlooked this.

Comment: @balanga You should mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @PhilHudson, I'm not really familiar with the format of this forum. How do I show my acceptance? Is there something I should click?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)